# increasing image size with GD and PHP

Tags: php, gd

i seem to be too dumb for this :-)

i have an image say
x=200
y=200

i want the image to stay the same but include a footer watermark lets say a.jpg which has a height of 20

so i want
a final image of 220 and y 200

i tried it this way but it wont work

```
$newimage=imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height+25);
imagecopy($newimage, $this->parentInstance->getOldImage(), 0, 0, 0, 0, $watermarksize[0], $watermarksize[1]);
imagecopy($newimage, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermarksize[0], $watermarksize[1]);
imagecopy($this->parentInstance->getOldImage(), $newimage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $dest_x, $dest_y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to lookup `imagecopymerge()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php

Answer (score 0):

Look at [image copy resized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php) if you want to resize an image resource using the GD library.